# Did Anakin ever return to free his mother?

Tags: star-wars

I just rewatched The Phantom Menace in theater. When leaving his mother, Anakin vows to come back and free her later. Does that ever happen in the movies? I have a vague memory of it happening, but I'm not sure if it was in fact of him freeing his mother.

What happened, and in what movie?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was in [Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones), excerpt from the plot section :

> [...] Meanwhile, Anakin becomes troubled by premonitions of his mother Shmi in pain. Despite Obi-Wan's orders to remain on Naboo, Anakin persuades Padmé to accompany him to Tatooine. After finding Shmi—tortured to death by a tribe of Tusken Raiders—Anakin snaps and kills the entire tribe before burying his mother.

Comment: SPOILER SPOILER: It's important to note that she was actually *alive* when he got there, but she died in his arms. Cruel timing.